# App controls user permissions on Mac

Tags: macos

So my company installed this app called "Sentinel One" on my mac remotely an overnight. This is scary in and out of itself given that I have set my user password myself, my Mac only has one admin user in System Preferences, and remote login, and remote management are all turned off from System Preferences.

In order to prevent this app from starting up at login I had to remove its LaunchDaemon and LaunchAgent from Library but I had a hard time doing it. I could easily remove all other Daemons and Agents even from system library but when trying to do that for this app I received warning that I did not have the required permission. Even tried changing the permission from file info but got the same error. I tried activating root user and doing this action through root user, did not work. I disabled "csrutil" from recovery mode and tried, did not work. The same permission error over and over again.

What worked was simply acting fast after booting and logging in and removing these files right before the program launched. I imagine booting from safe-mode would have worked too but did not try.

My question is: 1) How on earth does my corporate still install apps like this remotely? 2) How does an app like "Sentinel One" control user permissions for a certain file while the app is running?

Comment: Did your work provide you this Mac or did you buy it yourself?

Comment: Unix-like systems like macOS have built up a number of file protection schemes over the decades. In order to know what was going on, we would need to know the owner, group, permissions, flags, and ACLs for any and all of the files in question. For example, that security software may have been setting the "user immutable" (UCHG) flag on the files, and if you didn't about that flag and how to clear it, you could keep getting permissions errors when trying to delete it, that really had nothing to do with typical file protection mode ("chmod") permissions.

Comment: Anyone who can remotely install an antivirus already had permissions to do so - probably an MDM solution already installed by the company.

Comment: @Mokubai yes this MacBook was provided by the company.

Comment: @Tetsujin is Managed Software Center an example of an MDM? If so, if I uninstall it would it cut company from installing other random apps?

Comment: https://riverside.deskpro.com/kb/articles/what-is-managed-software-center-and-how-you-can-use-it If it's a company Mac you may be breaking your terms of employment by removing software they have installed. Golden Rule for company computers - don't mix business & pleasure. Don't put your own private details in it & don't use it for personal work.